# Any idea how to create scroll effects on wordpress like apple's ipad presentation?

Tags: wordpress, scroll

i'm trying to find a theme or plugin in order to create a site like this one https://www.apple.com/ipad-air/
On every scroll you see elements moving as well as when you reach on ipad the element remains sticky and the scroll is inside the ipad's screen.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for animation scrolling effect you can check https://scrollmagic.io/ , if you want ready made plugin for Wordpress then you can download https://codecanyon.net/item/scroll-magic-wordpress-scrolling-animation-builder-plugin/19418234?irgwc=1&clickid=zv-y723lpxyORtVwUx0Mo3Q1UkESDE3NOVT1XE0&iradid=275988&irpid=1266748&iradtype=ONLINE_TRACKING_LINK&irmptype=mediapartner&mp_value1=&utm_campaign=af_impact_radius_1266748&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=impact_radius   this WP plugin

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I have already checked the WordPress plugin